# Assessing numerical error in solving a least squares problem

Tags: linear-solver, stability, condition-number

I have a linear system of the type

$$Ax = b$$

I want to minimise $|b - Ax|^2$.
I know there are different approaches to directly solve the system (Normal equation + Cholesky, QR decomposition, SVD decomposition) that have different numerical stability.

I would like to ask how it is possible to estimate the impact of the numerical error on the estimates of each parameter $x$.

- Can it be done solely on the base of the condition number?
- Should it be done using Monte Carlo simulation?
- How should such simulation be designed?

Comment: Is your problem a linear system (square?), or a least squares problem $\min \|Ax-b\|$? Because the algorithms you list are the classical choices to solve LS problems, not to solve linear systems (even though some of those decompositions can do both jobs).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  You are right the question was unclear, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

I think most solvers will give you a residual error. If you flip your equation to read:

$Ax - b = r\approx 0$

The solver will usually provide you with the residual error like: $|r|$.

Now if you want to compare different solvers you might use that as a measurement of the error. As a rule of thumb: you will not find a solver which is optimal for every System A. Usually there are also speed/stability tradeofs or such.